# recyclerview for chat not display first message from bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I had implemented recyclerview for chat module but i had 1 problem that first message must be from bottom of screen but right now it is not possible it shows at top of screen and then it scrolls down so how can i set it to bottom. I had tried various things which are already listed at below but it not set

1) linearlayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`

2) In xml also

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"/>
```

3)

```
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
```

4) I also tried with below link also but not possible
[RecyclerView for chat app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423283/recyclerview-for-chat-app)

kindly help me.

Comment: try layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

Comment: layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

```
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: but not need more lines just add linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
  linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);