# how to display location message in chat window same like whatsapp in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I am developing a chat application. Where user can ***send location same like whatsapp***. (I am not talking about share live location functionality). For this requirement i have use google place picker api. Here I am attaching a code of that.

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in java file

```
 PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                dismiss();
                mActivity.startActivityForResult(builder.build(currentFragment.getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"GooglePlayServicesRepairableException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And this is how handled onActivityResult method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now after selecting that location want to display it similar to like this.
[image]

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Layout file :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#e0ffc6"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="11:00 AM"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Use this layout file as item file of recyclerview.

**For map image :**

Use this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674957/8089770

**To get lat long and name of place :**

`place.getLatLng()` to get the latitude and longitude

`place.getName()` to get Place name to show at bottom of map

**For chat application demo with recyclerview can go through tutorials like :**

1. https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChatMessagesAdapter-android
2. [RecyclerView for chat app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34423283/8089770)
3. https://www.dev2qa.com/android-chat-app-example-using-recyclerview/

Comment: khub khub abhaar.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to implement UI for showing audio and video in chat window like whatsapp?

Comment: @KushPatel sorry no idea about that.. but you can try with imageview, seekbar/progressbar, progressbar rounded with image in center. may be this way

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of static maps for that.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=9.9252,78.1198&zoom=14&markers=color:blue|label:A|9.9252,78.1198&size=500x400&sensor=false

You can replace the dynamic co-ordinates programmatically like below:

```
String location = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
                                + Utils.CUR_LATTITUDE
                                + ","
                                + Utils.CUR_LONGITUDE
                                + "&zoom=14&markers=color:blue|label:A|"
                                + Utils.CUR_LATTITUDE
                                + ","
                                + Utils.CUR_LONGITUDE
                                + "&size=500x400&sensor=false"
```

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to implement UI for showing audio and video in chat window like whatsapp?

Comment: it looks like it is no longer working like this, you need an API and a billing account to show this.

Answer (score 1):

follow this link google provide map thumbnail 
[link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)

Also, you can get this way 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=latitude,longitude&zoom=12&size=600x300&maptype=normal

Answer (score 1):

Add an XML attribute for a MapView or MapFragment in to you item view

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    map:uiMapToolbar="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:liteMode="true"/>
```

ViewHolder

```
public static class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView showMessage;
        public TextView ago, timeText;
        public ImageView seen;
        public MapView map;
        public ViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            showMessage= itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
            ago = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ago);
            seen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seen);
            map =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.map);
            timeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_time);
        }
    }
```

In your onBindViewHolder

```
        if (viewHolder2.map != null) {
            // Initialise the MapView
            viewHolder2.map.onCreate(null);
            viewHolder2.map.onResume();
            // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
            viewHolder2.map.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(chat.getLat(),chat.getLon()), 13f));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(chat.getLat(),chat.getLon())));

                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
            });
        }
```

End result:

[image]